# Add button to Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing

Tags: ribbon

This question is for anyone who wants to add a custom button to the Ribbon under the WikiPage or PublishTab tabs. The methods out there for adding a button that is associated with a list or library or file type do not seem to work for this particular scenario. The Button simply doesn't appear.

Here is the XML I am trying recently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.CheckLinkedPageItems"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    RegistrationType="List"
    RegistrationId="850"
    Sequence="40"
    Title="Move Documents">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.Controls._children">
          <Button
            Id="Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.CheckLinkedPageItemsButton"
            Alt="Check Linked Page Assets"
            Sequence="40"
            Command="CheckLinkedPageItems"
            Image32by32="/_layouts/images/ita/CheckLinked32.png"
            Image16by16="/_layouts/images/ita/CheckLinked16.png"
            LabelText="Check Assets"
            TemplateAlias="o1"
            ToolTipTitle="Check Linked Page Assets"
            ToolTipDescription="Checks each image, document and page linked to from this page and verified if the asset is both working (not a broken link) and published. You may also use that page to publish all unpublished assets at once."
            />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="CheckLinkedPageItems" CommandAction="javascript:alert('button clicked!);" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

I've tried several different combinations of RegistrationId and RegistrationType with no avail.

So far I've tried:

- List / 101
- List / 850 (id for Pages Library)
- FileType / aspx
- ContentType / 0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39 (ContentTypeId for 'page' content type)

Has anyone actually gotten this to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like all the examples out there are wrong, at least in this particular case. The TemplateAlias attribute needs to be c1, not o1.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: hello, hitdrumhard.. I am facing same issue for content type but I am not getting custom action placed in the Publish tab...

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried with the RegistrationId but take a look at my [blog post](http://www.cagataykalan.com/blog/custom-button-in-sharepoint-2010-ribbon-publishing-tab-part-1/) for putting it on the edit page

Comment: Your page seems to be down - would you mind posting your solution here?