# How to add custom action (custom tab) inside publishing page ribbon?

Tags: sharepoint-server, ribbon, custom-actions, custom-action

I've been working with Custom actions in the Ribbon over SharePoint 2013.

The problem is I would like to show a custom tab on the publishing ribbon.

I achieve show it everywhere but not in the publishing ribbon.

I've tried:

```
location = "CommandUI.Ribbon
Location = "CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView
```

and for the commanduiDefinition:

What should I do?

Many Thanks,
Ramon

Answer (score 1):

this been answered in the following post:
[Add button to Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35416/add-button-to-ribbon-publishtab-publishing)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.CheckLinkedPageItems"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    RegistrationType="List"
    RegistrationId="850"
    Sequence="40"
    Title="Move Documents">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.Controls._children">
          <Button
            Id="Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.CheckLinkedPageItemsButton"
            Alt="Check Linked Page Assets"
            Sequence="40"
            Command="CheckLinkedPageItems"
            Image32by32="/_layouts/images/ita/CheckLinked32.png"
            Image16by16="/_layouts/images/ita/CheckLinked16.png"
            LabelText="Check Assets"
            TemplateAlias="c1"
            ToolTipTitle="Check Linked Page Assets"
            ToolTipDescription="Checks each image, document and page linked to from this page and verified if the asset is both working (not a broken link) and published. You may also use that page to publish all unpublished assets at once."
            />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="CheckLinkedPageItems" CommandAction="javascript:alert('button clicked!);" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Comment: I found the post before. That was the first try and It didn't work! Did you tried it in SharePoint 2013?